# how do I create a stacked column chart with 3 different columns over each x-axis value

Tags: google-sheets, charts, stacked-chart

I want to make a stacked column chart with the data below. The workstreams would be on the x-axis and I would want three columns over each of them, one for each month, and the 'Reschedule' and 'Cancel' values would be stacked for each month. Not sure if this is possible, I've tried a couple things and can't get it to work.

[image: graph]

Comment: Could you share a sample of how you want the sheet to look? Normally this type of operations are carried out with [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've found is to set the series axes to left and right to separate them into columns. But this means that only two chart columns per x-axis data point.

So in your case, if you set up a stacked chart with the October and November values and then select each November series and change the Axis for each to the right, the two November values will be stacked in a column next to the stacked October values. Unfortunately, since there are only two axes, there's no way to then include the December values.

Original source is here: https://medium.com/@angellily0330/a-simple-way-to-create-clustered-stacked-columns-in-google-sheets-68792498d3ed